# alter regex to accept phone number with or without spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the regex to validate uk phone numbers but it is currently forcing the user to input a space before it will accept the number how do I alter it to make it accept numbers with or without spaces.

```
 /^0\d{2,4}[ -]{1}[\d]{3}[\d -]{1}[\d -]{1}[\d]{1,4}$/
```

Comment: Try putting a ? after the [ -]. Not exactly sure if it will work like that though. Might be better doing `\d{2,4}\w?-?[\d]{3}...` if \w is whitespace (could be \s or something else)

Comment: Please provide an input that it currently works for and an input that it needs to work for

Comment: this currently works 01324 765578 this does not 01324765578

Comment: btw, `{1}` quantificator is useless

Comment: or you could just get rid of spaces before verifying..

Comment: I think that pattern is completely wrong, are you sure that `[\d -]` parts are ok? This number would be ok: 01324 123456789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var reg = /^0\d{2,4}[ -]{0,1}[\d]{3}[\d -]{1}[\d -]{1}[\d]{1,4}$/;
var number ="01324 765578";
console.log(number.match(reg));

var number ="01324765578";
console.log(number.match(reg));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^0\d{2,4}[ -]{0,1}[\d]{3}[\d -]{0,1}[\d -]{0,1}[\d]{1,4}$/
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FgtL2/)

Comment: You can change the `{0,1}` to `?` for the same results